# React component not listing hidden.bs.modal (Modal hidden) event - Bootsrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap with jQuery in ReactJS.
I want to call a function when bootstrap modal close.
I've added two listener, one for show modal and second for hide modal,
But i'm getting only one `shown.bs.modal`. i've tried many tries with different different version but not working.

I've tried with bootstrap 3.3.6 to 4.3.1 with supported dependencies.
Currently i'm using these configs:-
jQuery - jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
Bootstrap - 4.3.1
PooperJs - 1.14.7

```
componentDidMount = () => {
      window.addEventListener('load', this.applyEvent)
}

applyEvent = () => {
 $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      console.log("show") // Working
    })
 $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      console.log("Just a rather - - show") // Not working
    })
}
```

i also tried with `show.bs.modal`, it's also working. But `hide.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal` both are not working. Something weird happing here. It should work also.

Comment: You really shouldn't use jQuery with React - use the Bootstrap native version which can be found here - https://github.com/thednp/bootstrap.native - it exposes all the Bootstrap methods without jQuery being required

Comment: Darren, I know about it. but it is used already here. so i can't remove it. Is there any solution for this problem.